# Is it possible to join subqueries using MongoDB aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Is there a MongoDB aggregation query equivalent to the following SQL statement using a single MongoDB aggregation? (The two operands of the JOIN are two subqueries that also include join operations.)

```
SELECT 
    T1.C1, T2.C2 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         T3.C1 C1, T4.C2 C2 
     FROM 
         T3 
     JOIN 
         T4 ON T3.C0 = T4.C0) T1
JOIN
    (SELECT 
         T5.C1 C1, T6.C2 C2 
     FROM 
         T5 
     JOIN 
         T6 ON T5.C0 = T6.C0) T2 ON T1.C1 = T2.C1 
                                 AND T1.C2 = T2.C2;
```

Comment: We can join the MongoDB collections one by one using $lookup if the second operand of the JOIN operation is a MongoDB collection. I'm interested in if we can still implement the join operation if the second operand is a subquey.

Comment: Document oriented databases like MongoDB are not optimized for joins, some NoSQL databases do not even support joins at all. Don't try to use a NoSQL database like a relational database - yes I know for a "classic" database developer this is can be a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - no, [lookup](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) requires "from" to be a collection.

As WD pointed out, SQL patterns do not work in NoSQL universe, yet database is a database - if data is there you can always fetch it. The logic will be inverted - you will do `SELECT T3.C1, T6.C2 FROM T3 and complex lookups/unwinds from T4, T5 and T6`.

Considering the OP's snippet, it would be fair to assume the question is more academic than practical. From this perspective - it's still "no". Don't design/denormalise data to the degree that you find yourself in the position where you need to run such query.

Answer (score 0):

This does not exactly address the OP question re. subqueries but show how, if absolutely necessary, "temporary" collections can be used in lieu of subqueries.  Note that in the original SQL, only tables `T3`.`T4`,`T5`, and `T6` actually exist; `T1` and `T2` are subquery constructs.  Also, the original SQL is not particularly useful because it only shows matching columns; we know nothing else about the rows from whence they came, so we will carry along `old_id` just for show.

It is highly likely that the SQL subquery is actually implicitly doing what we explicitly show here:  creating temporary tables `T1` and `T2` and not holding it in memory.

```js
db.XT3.drop();
var r = [
    {C0: "A", C1: "R0-1", C2: "R0-2"}
    ,{C0: "A", C1: "R1-1", C2: "R1-2"}
    ,{C0: "B", C1: "R0-1", C2: "R0-2"}
    ,{C0: "C", C1: "R0-1", C2: "R0-2"}
];
var nn = 0; r.forEach(function(d) { d['_id'] = nn++ }); // auto incr ID
db.XT3.insertMany(r);

db.XT4.drop();
var r = [
    {C0: "A", C1: "R0-1", C2: "R0-2"}
    ,{C0: "A", C1: "R2-1", C2: "R2-2"}
    ,{C0: "B", C1: "R0-1", C2: "R0-2"}
    ,{C0: "no_match", C1: "R0-1", C2: "R0-2"}
];
r.forEach(function(d) { d['_id'] = nn++ }); // auto incr ID
db.XT4.insertMany(r);


db.XT5.drop();
var r = [
    {C0: "X", C1: "nope", C2: "nope"}
    ,{C0: "X", C1: "R1-1", C2: "R1-2"}
    ,{C0: "Y", C1: "R0-1", C2: "R0-2"}
    ,{C0: "Z", C1: "R0-1", C2: "R0-2"}
];
r.forEach(function(d) { d['_id'] = nn++ }); // auto incr ID
db.XT5.insertMany(r);

db.XT6.drop();
var r = [
    {C0: "X", C1: "R0-1", C2: "R0-2"}
    ,{C0: "Y", C1: "R0-1", C2: "R0-2"}
    ,{C0: "oiwejfioj", C1: "R0-1", C2: "R0-2"}
];
r.forEach(function(d) { d['_id'] = nn++ }); // auto incr ID
db.XT6.insertMany(r);



db.TMP1.drop();
db.TMP2.drop();

c=db.XT3.aggregate([
    {$lookup: {"from": "XT4",
           let: { id: "$C0" },
           pipeline: [
           {$match: {$expr: {$eq: [ "$C0", "$$id" ]} }}
           ,{$project: {_id:false,C0:false}} // no need to carry them
           ],
           as: "T_3_4"
          }}

    // This ALSO acts to filter out items from XT3 with NO match to XT4:
    ,{$unwind: '$T_3_4'}

    // $unwind will dupe _id of inbound XT3 record; must get rid of it
    // in prep for $out; keep it around for debugging/tracking as 'old_id':
    ,{$project: {_id:false, old_id:'$_id', C1:'$C1', C2:'$T_3_4.C2'}}
    ,{$out: "TMP1"}
]);

db.XT5.aggregate([
    {$lookup: {"from": "XT6",
           let: { id: "$C0" },
           pipeline: [
           {$match: {$expr: {$eq: [ "$C0", "$$id" ]} }}
           ,{$project: {_id:false,C0:false}} // no need to carry them
           ],
           as: "T_5_6"
          }}
    ,{$unwind: '$T_5_6'}
    ,{$project: {_id:false, old_id:'$_id', C1:'$C1', C2:'$T_5_6.C2'}}    
    ,{$out: "TMP2"}
]);

c = db.TMP1.aggregate([
    {$lookup: {"from": "TMP2",
           let: { c1: "$C1", c2: "$C2" },

           // ON T1.C1 = T2.C1 AND T1.C2 = T2.C2;
           pipeline: [
           {$match: {$expr: {$and: [
               {$eq: [ "$$c1", "$C1" ]},
               {$eq: [ "$$c2", "$C2" ]}
           ]} }}
           ,{$project: {_id:false}}
           ],
           as: "X"
          }}

    // Filter out non-matches; comment out this stage to double check
    // docs where T1.C1 = T2.C1 AND T1.C2 = T2.C2 is NOT satisfied:
    ,{$match: {$expr: {$ne:[0, {$size:'$X'}]} }}
]);
emit(c);
```

yields

```js
{
  _id: ObjectId("655e1e5a4e762532ed9ba7aa"),
  old_id: 0,
  C1: 'R0-1',
  C2: 'R0-2',
  X: [
    {
      old_id: 10,
      C1: 'R0-1',
      C2: 'R0-2'
    }
  ]
}
{
  _id: ObjectId("655e1e5a4e762532ed9ba7ac"),
  old_id: 1,
  C1: 'R1-1',
  C2: 'R0-2',
  X: [
    {
      old_id: 9,
      C1: 'R1-1',
      C2: 'R0-2'
    }
  ]
}
{
  _id: ObjectId("655e1e5a4e762532ed9ba7ae"),
  old_id: 2,
  C1: 'R0-1',
  C2: 'R0-2',
  X: [
    {
      old_id: 10,
      C1: 'R0-1',
      C2: 'R0-2'
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The $out stage will create a new collection or replace an existing collection in the database.  Do we have other apporaches without writing the database?

Comment: Not directly, no, as indicated in the first answer.